# How to count the rows per sheet using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

The code below only count the total number of rows in sheet 1 but I also want to count the rows in sheet 2 and sheet 3 and so on

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("PATH", true))
{
    //Get workbookpart
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
    //then access to the worksheet part
    IEnumerable<WorksheetPart> worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts;
    foreach (WorksheetPart WSP in worksheetPart)
    {
        //find sheet data
        IEnumerable<SheetData> sheetData = WSP.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>();
        // Iterate through every sheet inside Excel sheet
        foreach (SheetData SD in sheetData)
        {
            IEnumerable<Row> row = SD.Elements<Row>(); // Get the row IEnumerator
            Console.WriteLine(row.Count()); // Will give you the count of rows
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct to me and works when I run it (although I end up with the sheets in reverse order). Do you definitely have more than one sheet?

Comment: Yes. But I need to get the counter of rows in each sheet but I am only getting the count for sheet 1